# $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sin (nx) = \cot(x/2)$?

Tags: trigonometry, trigonometric-series

I noticed this trend playing around in desmos, that the series $\sin x + \sin 2x + \sin 3x +...$ tends to $\cot(\frac{x}{2})$, is this identity correct?

Here is an example:

[image: with <span class=]$a=18$" />

Comment: Are you familiar with Fourier series?

Comment: Never formally taught, but I know the general idea of it. Is this a common Fourier series?

Comment: For the sum $\sum_1^\infty \sin(nx)$, experiment with some nice values of $x$.

Comment: I think it should be $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2\sin(k x) = \cot(\frac{x}{2})$$

Comment: The terms of the series do not approach zero.  Therefore, the series diverges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one would *formally* differentiate the well-known Fourier series
$$
\log|\sin(x/2)|=-\log 2-\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos nx}{n},\quad (x\neq 2\pi k,\ k\in\mathbf Z),
$$
one would get
$$
\frac{1}{2}\cot(x/2)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\sin(nx).
$$
Now, as it happens, one cannot just differentiate Fourier series as one wish. Note that, for general $x\in (0,2\pi)$, the terms $\sin(nx)\not\to 0$ (as also mentioned by @Dr.MV in a comment), so the series in the right-hand side does not converge.

One way out of this would be to interpret everything in terms of distributions.